# python-iptables installation error

Tags: python, python-iptables

I am trying to install `python-iptables` for Python27 but I get the following error after using `pip install python-iptables` and `easy_install python-iptables`

> libxtwrapper/wrapper.c(5) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/utsname.h': No such file or directory
>   error: command 'C:\Users\pinso\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

[Full log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsBgl.png)

Comment: Don't use images of text. This is a rule. Copy-and-paste text instead. You can edit your question.

Comment: rewritten part of the image log to text

Answer (score 0):

You install python-tables in windows OS, it only supports `POSIX :: Linux`[python-iptables readme](https://github.com/ldx/python-iptables/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: So no way I can use it on Windows OS, the thing is I want to deploy it on Heroku, you think it will work on Heroku as well?

Comment: So no way I can use it on Windows OS, the thing is I want to deploy it on Heroku, you think it will work on Heroku even if I just code it on my laptop and deploy on Heroku

Comment: Sorry, I have not used Heroku, but I think it can, you could try it.

Comment: Thank you very much Em L